# Compilation error when accessing overloaded operator of managed reference property

Tags: properties, reference, c++-cli, operator-overloading

I get the compilation error

> test.cpp(21) : error C2676: binary '+' : 'Manager ^' does not define
>   this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator

when trying to compile the following program.

```
public ref class Managed {};

public ref class Manager {
    public:
        Manager^ operator += (Managed^ m) { list->Add(m); return this; }
    private:
         System::Collections::Generic::List<Managed^>^ list;
};

public ref class Foo {
    public:
        property ::Manager^ Manager {
            ::Manager^ get() { return manager; }
        }
    private:
        ::Manager^ manager;
};

int main() {
    Foo^ foo = gcnew Foo;
    foo->Manager += gcnew Managed;  // Line 21
}
```

When I replace the `main` function with the one below, the program compiles.

```
int main() {
    Foo^ foo = gcnew Foo;
    Manager^ mgr = foo->Manager;
    mgr += gcnew Managed;
}
```

What is the essential difference between the two, that makes the one compile but not the other one?

Comment: Operator overloads are squirrely in C++/CLI, the CLS rules collide too heavy with C++ practices.  CLS demands that they are static members, the property is not an l-value.  They did the best they could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds533389.aspx), `operator+=` is not one of the allowable C++/CLI user-defined operators. Instead, `operator+` should be defined and the compiler will translate `+=` into `+` followed by `=` (assignment).

If you add an `operator+` to your `Manager` class and then add `set(::Manager^)` to your `Foo::Manager` property, the Line 21 compiles.